# Scanf function in C with CodeBlocks IDE is buggy?

Tags: c, scanf, short

I'm running some simple code in my CodeBlocks and I wonder why `scanf` function cannot work with shorts correctly!

The code below is an example.  The code takes from the user three `int` numbers and then prints them again, that simple — but the values printed don't match the values entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    short x, y, z;
    printf("Please enter three integers! ");
    scanf("%d %d %d", &x, &y, &z);
    printf("\n num1  =  %d  , num2 = %d  , num3  = %d ", x, y, z);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ....because you are using the wrong format specifier for short.

Comment: Also, if you enabled all the warnings the compiler would have warned you about this mistake (and recent versions of gcc even suggest che correct specifier).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specifier `%d` is only used for `int` variables, but in case of `short` you must use the `%hi` specifier instead of `%d`.

So your code must be :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   short x , y , z ;
   printf("Please Enter three int Numbers ! ");
   scanf("%hi %hi %hi",&x,&y,&z);
   printf("\n num1  =  %hi  , num2 = %hi  , num3  = %hi ",x,y,z);
   return 0;
}
```

You can find more information about the `C` data types and their Specifiers here :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types

Comment: Using the length modifier `h` is correct; demanding `%hi` is not — `%hd` would also work and might be safer.  Quickly: why does typing `09 08 07` as the inputs fail when you use `%hi` and not when you use `%hd`?  Be cautious! It would also be a good idea to show that the result of `scanf()` should be checked: `if (scanf("%hd %hd %hd", &x, &y, &z) == 3) printf("\nx = %d, y = %d, z = %d\n", x, y, z); else printf("Didn't manage to read three integers\n");`.  (Although it may be too much now, it's interesting to know why `%d` is OK in the formatting; overflow might be interesting to discuss, too.)

Answer (score 2):

short != int

you pass the pointer to the (usually 2 byte) data, and scanf expects and writes 4 bytes

change `short x , y , z ;` to `int x , y , z ;`

as always scanf is not buggy, but the coder is :)

PS Forgot to add. you can also use `h` format modifier. There is `hh` as well if you want to scan char sized variables